# Error with .\twitterfeed\node_modules\ionic-angular\package.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, node-modules

I created a new ionic app - twitterfeed.

When I enter the code - cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git

I get this error:

> [ERROR] Error with .\twitterfeed\node_modules\ionic-angular\package.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND

How do I solve this?

Comment: use `npm` to install the missing node module

Comment: Thanks @RolandWeber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the same command with --verbose at the end.
Also install cordova: npm install -g cordova to see if this fixes the problem.